# file_put_contents writes nothing for some strings

Tags: php

I'm working on the assets (css/js) compiler, but unfortunately for some of js files php returns correct result for file_put_contents (number of bytes written) when really nothing was written.

The algorithm looks like:

```
$file = 'path/to/compiled/file.js';
$content = file_get_contents('file.js');
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

I tried to use file locking, fopen()-fwrite(), but result is the same for js libs like jquery - I'm getting numbers of bytes written when the file stays empty without any errors or warnings.

Can it be memory limitation (it works fine on ubuntu, os x, and for that moment this issue appears only on virtualbox + vagrant)?

Comment: Is it possible there is a difference in permission on the two machines you mention?

Comment: Does vagrant has permissions to read your source file and write to your destination file? Check open_basedir option. Also you should check all of your pathes cause on virtual machichine them can be diffrent.